# Binding data to a textbox , inside a templatefield of a gridview » C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, templatefield

How can I bind data to a textbox which is in a templatefield of a gridview ?
I want to use ExecuteScalar , get a value and throw it to that textbox .

Answer (score 1):

Basically you create a method to return your value and then call it in the databinding expression.  Take a look at this example:

In your aspx page call the function GetValue in the data binding expression:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" Width="200px" runat="server" Text='<%#GetValue((int)Container.DataItem)%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in your code behind you have the function to get the value:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GridTest.DataSource = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};
    GridTest.DataBind();

}

protected string GetValue(int ID)
{
    return "Value from Execute Scalar " + ID;
}
```